# Lost Data Point in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a simple time series:

```
2015-05-03 07:00,58
2015-05-03 08:00,61
2015-05-03 09:00,65
2015-05-03 10:00,69
2015-05-03 11:00,72
2015-05-03 12:00,74
2015-05-03 13:00,76
2015-05-03 14:00,78
2015-05-03 15:00,78
2015-05-03 16:00,78
2015-05-03 17:00,77
2015-05-03 18:00,76
2015-05-03 19:00,73
2015-05-03 20:00,70
2015-05-03 21:00,67
2015-05-03 22:00,66
2015-05-03 23:00,64
2015-05-04 00:00,63
2015-05-04 01:00,62
2015-05-04 02:00,62
2015-05-04 03:00,61
2015-05-04 04:00,61
2015-05-04 05:00,60
2015-05-04 06:00,60
```

using:

```
reset

set terminal pngcairo enhanced background "#000000" font "Arial,10" size 600,200 truecolor
dataFileForecast = "/Users/.../Dropbox/Public/hourlyForecast.csv"
set datafile separator ','
stats dataFileForecast using 2 nooutput

freezeWarning = 32
Yhigh = (STATS_mean * 1.5)
Ylow = (STATS_mean - (STATS_mean * 0.5))

set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set output "/Users/.../Dropbox/Public/hourlyForecast.png"

set tics tc rgb "#666666"
set border lt rgb "#666666"
set boxwidth 0.25 relative

set style fill transparent solid 0.4
set style line 1 lt rgb "#666666" lw 1 pt 6
set style line 2 lt rgb "#0000FF" lw 1 pt 6

unset key
unset mxtics
set xdata time 
set xtics format "%H:%M"
set ytics format "%2.0f"
set yrange [Ylow:Yhigh] 

plot dataFileForecast using 1:2 every ::1 title column with filledcurve above y1=0 ls 1,\
     dataFileForecast using 1:2:2 every ::1 with labels offset 0,1 tc "#FFFFFF" font "Lato-Light,8",\
     freezeWarning with filledcurve above y1=0 ls 2
```

Works okay, but I lose the first data points for some reason (the plot should start with 07:00, and show 24 data points):

[image: time series plot]

I cannot figure out how to get the plot to start with the first data point. (After that's accomplished, what I'd really like to do is put a 1 hour buffer on either side -- in other words, have the xrange be [dataPoint1-(60*60):dataPoint24+(60*60)]

Any help would be most appreciated.

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `title column` you tell gnuplot to use the first line as key titles. And with this, the first line is skipped for plot. Then, the `every ::1` part would also skip the first line. Remove both and you get the expected plot.

To extend the xrange by 1 hour to each side, use `set offsets 60*60,60*60,0,0` together with `set autoscale xfix`:

```
reset

set terminal pngcairo enhanced background "#000000" font "Arial,10" size 600,200 truecolor
dataFileForecast = "test.dat"
set datafile separator ','
stats dataFileForecast using 2 nooutput

freezeWarning = 32
Yhigh = (STATS_mean * 1.5)
Ylow = (STATS_mean - (STATS_mean * 0.5))

set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set output "test.png"

set tics tc rgb "#666666"
set border lt rgb "#666666"
set boxwidth 0.25 relative

set style fill transparent solid 0.4
set style line 1 lt rgb "#666666" lw 1 pt 6
set style line 2 lt rgb "#0000FF" lw 1 pt 6

unset key
unset mxtics
set xdata time 
set xtics format "%H:%M"
set ytics format "%2.0f"
set yrange [Ylow:Yhigh]
set autoscale xfix
set offsets 60*60,60*60,0,0

plot dataFileForecast using 1:2 with filledcurve above y1=0 ls 1,\
     dataFileForecast using 1:2:2 with labels offset 0,1 tc "#FFFFFF" font "Lato-Light,8",\
     freezeWarning with filledcurve above y1=0 ls 2
```

[image]

Comment: Of course!  Thanks for that.  I pulled the code over from another one of my plots which does have a title row, and then a color row after that.  I knew it was something like that.  Brilliant!  -- Thanks very much.